# Нужна ли запятая после "нас"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Девчата, а вы что тут без нас и бутылку уже открыть успели?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Девчата, **а вы что тут без нас**, и бутылку уже открыть успели?*

Делается пауза и ставится запятая **перед союзом И**.

Здесь возможны еще такие варианты:

(1) *Девчата, **а вы что**, бутылку уже открыли?*

(2) *Девчата, **а вы что**, и бутылку без нас уже открыть успели?*

Но вариант (2) не очень удобен для чтения.

Таким образом, мы можем менять актуальное членение предложения, в том числе  отнести сочетание ***тут без нас*** к первой (вопросительной) части.

Comment: Все говорят, что пауза после *тут без нас,* а я всё-таки говорю без паузы, просто резко повышаю там тон.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

> *Девчата, а вы что, тут без нас и бутылку уже открыть успели?*

После ***нас*** запятой не нужно. Зато она нужна после ***а вы что.*** Цитирую [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131):

Слова ***что, а что, что же,*** обозначающие вопросы, и слова ***как, как же, что же,*** выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми следует предложение, *раскрывающее их конкретный смысл (после них делается пауза), **отделяются запятой:*** ***Что,*** если я кликну клич? (Т.) — ‘что будет, если…’; ***Что,*** если в самом деле он [городничий] *потащит меня в тюрьму?* (Т.); ***Что,*** ему лет двадцать пять, не больше? (Л. Т.); ***А что,*** если он прячется в глубине лесов? (Каз.); ***Как,*** разве всё тут? Шутите! (П.); ***Как же,*** я готов сию минуту (Г.).

Паузу при произнесении также правильнее делать после *"что",* а не перед *"и".* Хотя теперь я заметил, что и там её не делаю, а перед *"и"* без паузы резко повышаю тон.

Comment: Может, и "правильнее", но в основном делают после "нас". Там же и запятую ставят.